# How to handle multiple columns of Data from Excel using Apache POI for Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, java

I am new to Selenium WebDriver and I am automating an end to end test. My doubt here is, all the data for the test is stored in an excel file which contains more than 15 columns of data. Each @Test annotation (I am using TestNG) requires one or two or three of the column data. Basically I need to split the 15 Columns of data according to the @Test annotations (for each single action). How exactly to do this? Every time using @DataProvider and creating two or three parameters for the same and writing the code to read data seems to be too redundant. Kindly help me here on how to do tackle this in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Read the complete excel at the start of your test, store the column headers in a array/list and then by using the first row as column header feed your test e.g. in a Test annotation, you require data for Firstname, Lastname and Address columns only.

Then, in that test write the code to read values of rows below the column Firstname and insert the same into the Firstname field. This way you don't need to care about the order in which your excel has been created i.e. whether Firstname is at the 2nd column or 14th column it doesn't matter. Below is the code for that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com"); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); 

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:\\Dhiman\\Automation\\seleniumtest.xls"); 
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            int noOfColumns = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
            //System.out.println(noOfColumns);
            String[] Headers = new String[noOfColumns];
            for (int j=0;j<noOfColumns;j++){
                Headers[j] = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
            }
                for (int a=0;a<noOfColumns;a++){
                    if(Headers[a].equals("Address")){
                        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(1).getCell(a).getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                        }
}
      workbook.close();
      file.close();
      driver.close();
      System.exit(0);
            }
```

using this need to get the value of 2-3 columns as required by you and can fill the respective field in the application. I haven't used TestNG in my tests, but you will get a clear idea from this implementation.

Comment: +1, its a clever idea to put fields into an array. I would suggest to use a switch case condition instead of if-else at the place where Column name comparison happens (it's more efficient and keeps code neat).

Answer (score 0):

```
package DDT;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadExcelSheet {
    public static HSSFWorkbook WBook = null;
    public static HSSFSheet WSheet= null;

    public static HSSFSheet DataSheet(String FilePath, String SheetName){
        File file = new File(FilePath);
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            WBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            WSheet = WBook.getSheet(SheetName);         
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return WSheet;      
    }       

}


package DDT;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class getExcelData extends ReadExcelSheet {

    public static Object[][] LoginData;
    public static Object[][] ShipmentData;
    public static HSSFRow Row;
    public static HSSFCell cell;
    public static String FilePath = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\DataSheet.xls";
    public static String SheetName1 = "Login";
    public static String SheetName2 = "Shipment";
    public static HSSFSheet Sheet;

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] getLoginData() throws Exception{

        Sheet = DataSheet(FilePath, SheetName1);
        int rowCount = Sheet.getLastRowNum();
        System.out.println(rowCount);
        int colCount = Sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        System.out.println(colCount);

        LoginData = new Object[rowCount][colCount];

        for (int rCnt=1; rCnt<=rowCount;rCnt++){
            for (int cCnt=0; cCnt<colCount;cCnt++){
                LoginData[rCnt-1][cCnt] = getCellData(SheetName1, rCnt, cCnt);
                System.out.println(LoginData[rCnt-1][cCnt]);
            }
        }

        return LoginData;
    }
        @DataProvider
        public static Object[][] getShipmentData() throws Exception{

            Sheet = DataSheet(FilePath, SheetName2);
            int rowCount = Sheet.getLastRowNum();
            System.out.println(rowCount);
            int colCount = Sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
            System.out.println(colCount);

            ShipmentData = new Object[rowCount][colCount];

            for (int rCnt=1; rCnt<=rowCount;rCnt++){
                for (int cCnt=0; cCnt<colCount;cCnt++){
                    ShipmentData[rCnt-1][cCnt] = getCellData(SheetName2, rCnt, cCnt);
                    System.out.println(ShipmentData[rCnt-1][cCnt]);
                }
            }

            return ShipmentData;        
    }

    public static String getCellData(String Sheet, int row, int col){

        try {

            int index = WBook.getSheetIndex(Sheet);


            WSheet = WBook.getSheetAt(index);
            Row = WSheet.getRow(row);
            if (Row == null)
            return "";

            cell = Row.getCell(col);
            if (cell == null)
            return "";

            switch (cell.getCellType())
            {
            case  Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            return cell.getStringCellValue();               

            case  Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());          

            case  Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            return "";      

            case  Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            return cell.getStringCellValue();           

            case  Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            return String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());          

            default:
            return "Cell not found";        

            }
        }
            catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "row " + row + " or column " + col+ " does not exist in xls";
            }

    }

    @Test(dataProvider="getLoginData")
    public void TC01_Verify_Login_Valid_Cred(String User, String Pass){

    System.out.println(User + Pass);    
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="getShipmentData")
    public void TC02_Verify_Shipment_Data(String TestID,String Weight, String Account,String DeclaredValue,String Execute,String Status){

    System.out.println(TestID+Weight+Account+DeclaredValue+Execute+Status); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer to explain how your answer differs from the other answer and how it solves the original question? That will make this a much more useful answer

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to handle excel data using POI as well as JXL jar in selenium.Mostly for jxl jar/POI you have to use `Dataprovider` in TestNG for easy purpose.
You can find more details in this article ,it has given datadriven framework implemention here .[Reading data from excel](http://www.wikishown.com/selenium-tutorials/data-driven-framework-with-selenium/)

Comment: If you wrote the article, you must state this when you link to it. Otherwise you could be flagged for spam. See more information here: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/behavior especially the phrase "you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers".